# jQuery click on <select>

Tags: jquery, select, onclick

OnClick event is fired when I select option. But I want to catch event before dropdown list will open.

```
$('#my_select').click(function(){
   alert('clicked');
});
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qjx07fzk/

Comment: Use `console.log` to debug and this works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/qjx07fzk/1/

Comment: Oh, I see this works fine in Firefox...

Comment: In my Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) Ubuntu 15.10) I see 'clicked' after second click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onMousedown event works fine in this case.

```
$('#my_select').on('mousedown', function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qjx07fzk/4/